# Lightroom 6 and "Hardware acceleration"

Tags: lightroom, adapter, lightroom-6

I have an HP Laptop with Windows 8.1 (64 bit) with AMD Radeon HD 7620G + AMD Mobility Radeon HD 8670M dual graphics adapter {2 GB VRAM}, 8 GB System RAM, the 8670M being set as the primary adapter for Lightroom. I have updated the drivers from HP update to the latest, so I am sure the drivers are the latest and the most compatible to my system.

My problem started when I checked the "Hardware Acceleration" check-box in Lightroom-6. Lightroom crashes randomly, sometimes when I am navigating through my photos, sometimes when I do an adjustment from the Basic panel, and sometime while exporting the photos for web/print. This is getting me crazy.... These problems didn't occur if I unchecked the check-box for Hardware acceleration. {The openGL version as per Adobe website supporting Lightroom Hardware acceleration should be 3.3 or greater... My Graphics adapter passes the test in the "System Info..." information panel when I checked!)

Anyone else facing this problem?  What did you do for it? I really want to use the Hardware acceleration feature, since it might speed up my processing time drastically...

Comment: Have you tried disabling the lesser adapter altogether?

Comment: Yes JoanneC...I tried disabling each of the adapter, one by one... still the same issue.

Comment: Happens to me all the time when this option is enabled *on Mac OS X*. German magazine *Heise* sees no speed advantages in LR 6 by the way, it is considerable slower than Lightroom 5 in their tests (http://m.heise.de/foto/artikel/Nachgemessen-GPU-Beschleunigung-in-Lightroom-6-und-Lightroom-CC-2626770.html?seite=9&from-classic=1)

Comment: That heise article seems strange, as GPU acceleration is only used in develop module, which they explicitly didn't test, and nothing they tested uses it.

Comment: Yes, the article seems a little skewed...The GPU acceleration generally works on the Develop module (which they plainly ignored, saying it is difficult to measure that), where we see the changes in real time. The article mostly talks about import/export and rendering. {What I understood, by google translation of the page from German to English}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly check that in the AMD panel you can configure which graphic card is used when Lightroom is started.

Perhaps disable one of the graphic cards before starting Lightroom.

Moreover, a good solution is to completely uninstall the drivers, clean them, then reboot and install the drivers again. This is just to be sure you have a "clean install" of the graphic driver.

Check also that you put Lightroom on the exclusion list of your antivirus software...

Comment: This is awesome... I did the following and Lightroom don't have problems yet...And yes it's fast:  a.) I had checked disabling each of the Graphics adapter, one by one. The issue was still there.  b.) Lightroom was already set to use the higher version Graphics card (in my case, the Radeon 8670M)

Comment: c.) I went to safe mode in my Windows 8.1 system, completely uninstalled the graphics driver, and rebooted. I then went to "Device Manager" and refreshed the snap-in. It showed up the two Graphics driver. I then installed the driver downloaded from HP website, and changed the default driver for Lightroom to the higher version of the graphics. Fired up Lightroom, did some processing, waited for some time, again reprocessed some photos...No issues.   So I guess, that might be the issue - A clean install of the driver helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case having the current drivers may be part of your issue.
Lightroom has reportedly had issues with some combinations of AMD cards and drivers, see the link below.

https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/lightroom-amd-graphics-cards.html

You may have to try with a different driver.
On a personal note, I have found the GPU accelleration not very useful overall. While some aspects of editing are accelerated it also seems to make LR more sluggish sometimes on my NVIDIA GPU based systems (both laptop and desktop). For it seems to be a wash and I have left GPU support disabled for, but I will be testing again with every LR and driver update.